# Adding "</a>" after img with jQuery adds it before the element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm working with a .NET application that's being developed by a different company. They've allowed me to inject my own js and css file so I'm using jQuery to modify their HTML.

We have thumbnails in the top left corner of articles and I'm adding a lightbox to the image by adding code before and after the thumbnail to add a link.

**However** it doesn't work and for some reason both parts end up before the image if I inspect the element in Firebug. Could it be because the img element isn't properly closed?

My HTML (exactly, as I can't edit it without js):

```
<div class="news-image">
     <img src="image.jpg?thumb=1" alt="Article with picture ">
</div>
```

My jQuery:

```
$(".news-image img").each(function(){
    var newsimgurl = $(this).attr("src").replace('thumb=1','thumb=0');

    $(this).before('<a href="'+newsimgurl+'" data-lightbox="lightbox">');
    $(this).after('</a>');

});
```

What I end up with:

```
<div class="news-image">
     <a href="image.jpg?thumb=0" data-lightbox="lightbox"> </a>
     <img src="image.jpg?thumb=1" alt="Article with picture ">
</div>
```

Comment: The DOM isn't a string of HTML. There's no adding a "start" and "end" of an element. You just add the whole element object and add content to it.

Comment: @squint: Oooh, really well put, I'll have to remember and shamelessly reuse that.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder: Please do! :)

Comment: Thank you @squint, I was not aware of that. I've not been using javascript for that long and am still learning all the details of modifying the DOM.

Comment: You're welcome. The DOM becomes much simpler when you realize it's just an object tree structure. Everything in your HTML gets converted into some object representation in the structure.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You're thinking in markup, but the browser only uses markup when converting from text to DOM elements. Once you're dealing with the DOM, you're dealing with *objects*.

In your case, you want to create an `a` object, insert it where the `img` is, and move the `img` into it. As it happens, jQuery has a function for that: [`wrap`](http://api.jquery.com/wrap/):

```
$(".news-image img").each(function(){
    var newsimgurl = $(this).attr("src").replace('thumb=1','thumb=0');

    $(this).wrap('<a href="'+newsimgurl+'" data-lightbox="lightbox"></a>');
});
```

Comment: Thank you for the complete answer. This made it work!

Comment: @T.J.Crowder No problem. Definitely one of the funnier typos I've fixed!